# Why is it creating an empty row in the csv file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write data to a csv file but it's creating an empty row each time the code executes. What is going wrong there?

```
  data = []
with open ("employee_data.csv","r") as employee_data:
                reader = csv.reader(employee_data)
                user_id = "336456"
                
                for row in reader:
                     if row[0] == user_id:
                       
                         
                        leave_type = "n"

                        row.append(leave_type)
                     data.append(row)
                        
with open ("employee_data.csv","w") as employee_data:
    writer = csv.writer(employee_data)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

The data comes out like this with a space which is an extra line:
[image]

How can I remove it? Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: What is this: `rough the selection box`.

Comment: Was a typo, removed it now :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather from your code, it looks like your csv file has empty rows that are being read into the `data` list, which you are then promptly writing back into the file.

Have you verified that your original csv file doesn't have blank spaces/rows?

Comment: The csv initially had no data except from the first line: 33645, A,S. I ran the code to insert the letter n into that row. However, when I do that it also inserts a blank line underneath that row and this is something that I want to prevent. How can I do that?